# Creating log for each table in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

[image]

In my database I have a log table for each table like in the picture. And after each CRUD operation on a table, I update the corresponding log table.

Is there some generic way in EF 4.1 (using `DbContext`) to perform insertion of records in each log file? Keep in mind that both `ID` columns are identity columns.

Comment: That would *probably* be a better task for a trigger on those tables... (or a feature like *Change Data Capture* in SQL Server 2008)

Comment: Thanks for responding but the problem is that The USER field in Tbl_ProductPriceList_DMLLog is come from Business Logic layer, and we can't find at it trigger time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no listener technic in EF, alternatively how about using general AOP tool such as Spring.NET or PostSharp so that you can capture the insert logic and store log into database or file.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding DbContext.SaveChanges seems to be accepted solution for what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you overriding the DbContext.SaveChanges it will gives you the track functionality but there is an hurdle in case of Newly inserted row, It will not get the Value of autoIdentity column value.